# Initialize @EJB fields

Tags: java, spring, jboss, ejb

I am newbie in EJB.

I have a class with following fields

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class MyServiceFacadeBean implements MyServiceFacadeLocal, MyServiceFacadeRemote {

    @EJB(name = "ejb/CatalogService")
    private CatalogService catalogService = null;
    ....
}
```

I have instantiated the object while injecting it implementation in Sring IOC:

```
<bean id="contestServiceFacade" class="my.company.service.facade.contest.ejb.MyServiceFacadeBean">
 </bean>
```

but after invoke it methods in my controllers I get **NullPointerException** on *catalogService* field. So how should be my facade correctly instantiated?

**UPDATE 1**: I have tried to plug bean with another approach asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765415/plug-bean-to-jboss-with-jndi). Maybe it will help while answering this question.

**UPDATE 2:** I cant change sources of mine EJBs but can do it for mine controllers.

Comment: Choose between Spring and EJBs. Using EJBs in a Spring environment doesn't make much sense, and vice-versa. They provide the same services, but differently. Spring doesn't have EJBs, and doesn't understand EJB annotations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can not do it, I am just assembler and should deploy these things so can't change app architecture. As for EJBs at Spring see this http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html So not big deal to use it simultaneously

Comment: And if you *read* the documentation you linked to, you'll notice that you need to configure a proxy for the EJB in the Spring XML file, and that you can't use the EJB annotation to inject a reference to the EJB in your controller, since EJB is not an annotation that Spring uses for injection. Use Autowired instead.

Comment: Well thanks I've tried proxy approach already but without luck (pls, see reference on my related question in the Update section). I'm not sure whether Autowire approach can be used if I can't change the code of my EJBs. Could you please be more verbose here or provide some example code?

Comment: It's simple. Spring doesn't care about the `@EJB` annotation. It won't read them or use them for anything. If you want to inject a Spring bean (the proxy declared in the XML file) into another Spring bean (your controller), you must use the Spring Autowired annotation in the controller. Not the EJB annotation.

Comment: And you shouldn't declare the MyServiceFacadeBean class as a Spring bean, as it would not be an EJB anymore. The only thang you can do is declare a Spring bean Proxy, as explained in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: OK I understand, so for correct injectiion I need Spring Autowired annotation in the controller but I think this is the second step of successful EJB injection because my Proxy bean (or how does it call) can not be deployed to JBoss yet (I mean my error in linked question). Am I right?

Comment: The XML snippet you have in your question is wrong. It doesn't create a proxy for the EJB. Read the documentation you linked to. It has an example of what you need.

Comment: I am SURE that XML snippet is correct because it is part of 100% workable/deployable project (but for JBoss 4). But nevertheless I've tried approach with Proxy declaration from my link but without luck - I have almost the same error now: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyServiceFacadeBean not bound

Comment: That's because you're not using the right JNDI name. Fix the JNDI name. The JBoss console or documentation tells what JNDI name each deployed EJB has. And you're sure, but you're wrong. The XML snippet creates a Spring bean, but this Spring bean is created by Spring, and not by the EJB container, so it's not an EJB anymore. So no transaction, no JNDI binding, and no EJB injection anymore, which is precisely why your catalogService is not injected, and why you thus get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Yep, I'm not so strong in all this EJB staff. Please point to my mistake. How should jndi name be fixed? How to choose correct name? Where can I find all bound names at JBoss? See my fail try here: http://pastebin.com/RKeDjM2Z

Comment: Can you provide the log of the start up of the application, so we can make sure the EJB are deployed correctly.  If you need to integrate EJB with Spring the EJB need to be deployed by the Java EE container (Jboss) and then Spring will retrive it via JNDI.

Comment: Better tell what should I look at the log for ensuring EJB were deployed. I think they not deployed because I did not make any steps for this because I do not know what should they be. Actually this is the core of my question.

Comment: Jboss should give you the list of deployed EJBs with there JNDI names.  Which version of Jboss are you using?  What is the layout of your application archive.

Comment: I use JBoss 5.0.1. I do not see deployed EJBs at service=JNDIView at JBoss jmx-console. The layout of my app is: http://pastebin.com/Yanffr0z

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JBoss 5 you can't put the `EJB` in the war.  You need to create a ear file with the `EJB` `jar` and the `war` file (+the lib jars).  More information about `ear` can be find in the JavaEE tutorial ( http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html).

When the EJBs are correctly packaged in the ear they will be started by Jboss when deployed.

The Spring will be able to access them via JDNI as describe here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html

The other option is to switch to Jboss 7 as there `EJB` can be in `war`.  But this will required some effort as they change loth of thing in Jboss 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Spring to inject properties in your EJB, you need to use an Interceptor on your class:

```
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class MyServiceFacadeBean ... {

        @Autowired
        private CatalogService catalogService;

        ...
}
```

Comment: I can't change the source of mine EJBs

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing EJB and Spring beans. The annotation @EJB is to get enterprise java beans not a Spring bean.
You should change to an @Autowired annotation or change the CatalogService to be an EJB (with the correct EJB annotations in the class) and

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo" />
```

in the xml file.

Also note that you'll need a container that support EJB like Glassfish, JBoss (Tomcat is not).

Comment: I use JBoss 5. And I can;t change EJB's code. I need to correctly deploy it. Writing correct applicationContext.xml and some another stuff for pluging Enterprise Java Beans is my problem here.

Comment: As mentioned multiple time Spring beans are not EJBs and EJBs are not Spring beans. You need to make a choice about how you'll inject your beans. If you need to use Spring, change '@EJB to '@Autowired

Comment: 1) I know difference between Spring beans and EJBs beans. I need to deploy EJBs in my app. If it possible to do without changing Spring context it OK if it needs to change Spring context - tell what should be changed? 2) As I've said multiple times I can't changes the sources of mine EJBs but I can changes sources for my controllers that use these EJBs.

Comment: I may not have been clear enough in my answer. In the applicationContext.xml, remove the bean and add the tag above with the correct package. Should work